# ¿Cómo seleccionar parámetros de un DataFrame?

Tags: r, funciones

Intento crear una función que aplique *kmeans* y retorne **la Inercia total intragrupos**. El problema se presenta al tratar de seleccionar sólo algunas variables de la planilla que paso como parámetro.

Me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

```
> MiKMeans("D:/PRUEBAS en R/K MEANS","Ingresantes97.xls",6,1)
Error in excelFile[, c(2, 7, 10, 22, 25)] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

Y la tabla a la que accedo tiene 29 variables.

**¿Es posible realizarlo? ¿Y de qué manera?**

El código de mi función es el siguiente:

```
MiKMeans<-function(workingFolder, excelFile, cantgrupos,formulaOption)
{
    setwd(workingFolder)
    library ("readxl")
    if (file.exists(excelFile)){
       if (formulaOption==1)
          myData <-excelFile[,c(2,6,10,24,25)]  
            else
              if (formulaOption==2)
                myData <-excelFile[,c(2,6,10,22,24,25)]

        Ingreso<-as.data.frame(scale(myData))   
        set.seed(80)   
        Ingreso.km<-kmeans(Ingreso,cantgrupos)  
        return(Ingreso.km$tot.withinss) 
    }           
    else    print ("Error. No existe el archivo ") 
    return(Ingreso.km$tot.withinss)
}
```

Comment: Cuando intentas hacer esto: `excelFile[,c(2,6,10,24,25)] ` imagino que estás suponiendo que `excelFile`es un `data.frame`, pero `excelFile` es un nombre de archivo, es decir una cadena. En ninguna parte de tu código, estás leyendo dicho archivo.

Comment: Intuyo que te has olvidado usar `read_excel()` como lo hacías en tu otra pregunta

Comment: Si supuse mal. Lo modifiqué así:MiKMeans<-function(workingFolder, excelFile, cantgrupos,formulaOption)
{
 setwd(workingFolder)
 library(readxl)
 Planilla <-read_excel(excelFile)
        if (file.exists(excelFile)){
    if (formulaOption==1)
       myData <-Planilla[,c(2,6,10,24,25)] .........idem a lo que tenia

Comment: Pero ahora me aparece el siguiente error: > MiKMeans("D:/PRUEBAS en R/K MEANS","Ingresantes97.xls",6,1)
Error in file.exists(File) : invalid 'file' argument QUE ESTOY HACIENDO MAL???

Comment: Me imagino que es por que por un lado estás pasando un `workingFolder` y por el otro un `excelFile`, no será que el nombre del archivo Excel debiera ser en todo caso algo así `paste0(workingFolder, "/", excelFile)`

Comment: Si funcionó!. Pensé que al establecer el directorio no era necesario indicar su path.

Comment: @Claudia Si el problema ya está solucionado puedes publicar una respuesta a tu pregunta y marcarla como correcta.